# How to resize an image in a stream (using minimal RAM)?

Tags: java, image, image-resizing

Looking for something like djpeg which uses O(1) RAM to resize by sub sampling, but in java and able to handle jpg, png, gif, bmp, etc. Maybe some implementation already exists.
How to resize an image in a stream (using minimal RAM)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The [twelvemonkeys](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) jars enable reading of non RGB jpegs
- `setSourceSubSampling` and `setSourceRegion` permit resizing images in a stream.
- Progressive jpegs are not supported
- Large output files are not supported

Example:

```
File javaStreamSubsample(File inFile, int s, Rectangle sourceRegion) throws IOException  {
    File outFile = File.createTempFile("img", null);;
    ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(inFile);
    try {
        Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input);
        ImageReader reader = readers.next();
        try {
            reader.setInput(input);
            ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
            param.setSourceSubsampling(s, s, 0, 0);
            if(sourceRegion!=null){
                param.setSourceRegion(sourceRegion);
            }
            BufferedImage image = reader.read(0, param);
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outFile);
        }finally {
            reader.dispose();
        }
    } finally {
        input.close();
    }
    return outFile;
}
```

Comment: Can you add how you calculated s?

Comment: @ndtreviv ImageReader.getWidth gives you the width of the file and they you can just calculate the % from that and the output size

Answer (score 6):

The `FileImageInputStream` doesn't know anything about specific image formats, it's just convenience for reading ints, shorts, bytes, byte arrays, etc, from a file-backed input. File format support is handled by the various `ImageReader` implementations.

The short answer to your question is: You can't really resize an image without loading it.

From the description of djpeg:

> **djpeg** *decompresses* the named JPEG file [...]

(Emphasis is mine)

However, you can subsample images, wich is really fast (for most formats), and will uses less memory. Have a look at the `ImageReadParam.setSourceSubSampling` method and the `ImageReader.read(int, ImageReadParam)` method. This will create a resized image, quite similar to the "nearest neighbour" or "point sampling" algorithms (ie. the results won't necessary look good).

It's possible to combine subsampling first, with better quality resizing afterwards, to save memory, and possibly get acceptable results. It all depends on what quality you expect/need.

If you really, really want to resize images without loading them into heap memory (perhaps your images are huge), I've written some classes that use [memory mapped files](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox-common/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/MappedImageFactory.java) you can look at, but they are painfully slow.

Comment: fascinating impl with the mmapped-backed images; never thought of this before!

[[to OP]] the main problem is that all the image operations in Java operate on a BufferedImage -- a BufferedImage represents a *decoded* (and fully loaded) image so doing processing in-stream is not supported across any of the image types although you can sort of do something interesting with JPG as Harald pointed out -- in addition to decoding specific regions.

PNG, BMP and GIF you are back needing to decode the entire image again though.

Comment: @user1133275 In theory it could be possible to create a "streaming pixels" API, by decoding a minimum unit of pixels before feeding it to the next "consumer" in a chainable fashion. There's a library called [PNGJ](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj/) that allows reading (some) PNGs line by line, but it's still not exactly streaming... I've thought quite a bit about this during the years, because I see some use cases for such a library, and I'd like to do it. Maybe if someone pays me to do it. :-)